# байты в строку и наоборот из файла

Tags: python, стеганография

я делаю модуль для стеганографии, и мне нужна была функция удаления закодированного сообщения

И так есть код:

```
def remove_text(filepath):
m = None
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    m = str(data).split('2d2a2a2d')[0]
```

после его выполнения в `m` храниться что то такое: 
``` \xd5\x93+\x9eFJ\xa2\xfc\xe4\xf3\xc0\xae\x1bV\x94\x08.J\xb1\x08\x01\x8d\x963\xf3\xa9e8\x00u\xe3\x9c\x9e\xd5\xc3V\xa2\x8a\xf7\x99\xdfF\x9bG\x9cF\x1eGm\xdc.\xe0\xa8\x08\xfb\xd9==\xab\xd1\xf4\rBD\xbd\x85``\x08\xab\x1al\x90cz\x00Wi \x1c\xf3\xd4\xf1\xd3\xb61\xc61\xad\x1d\x8d\xaaB\\\xb6=\xfbB\xd6R\xd9\xa3u\xb8\x8d\xe61\x98\xe3Dl\xf9\x9b\x81\'\x03\xb9\xc6q\x9eEv\xb6Z\xfa\xcb\x18\x90\xc8\xc5\xbea(\x91p\x8a\xa3\x8d\xd9\xcf\xae\x7f/z\xe9Ub\xf4g\x9f:s\xea\xc6]j\x05\xe3\xb8\x8e\x12\x80\x91\xf7\xddCq\x9c\xf4=\xfd\x0ek\x91\xd4.\xd9\xaeS\xc8\x980\xb8\x03\xe4c\xbdc?\xdf\xcf\xa9\xeb\xc9#\x81\xc0\xef\x8c\xd77\xbc\xf4.\x95+\xb4\xa4\xca\xf0\xcd4[\xbf\x7f\x1c\x9fy\x18:\xab\x91\xb8\x10~\x87\x9e\x0e8\xf5\xcdj\xdaO\x0c\xa7\xcaI\x0c\xb2\x90\t\xde\x85\x19~\x9c\x9c\x83\xeb\xf5\xaf.\xbb\xa0\xa2\xef-U\xef\xe4z\xd40\xcd;\xa9#v\x0bu&E nP\x08|\xe3\xf4\xfc\xbfZ\xdc\x8a[u\x92\xd3\x12G3[\xa7\x97\'\x92\xac\x9b\xc6\xe2NI\x1dpq\xc7e\x15\xe6\xd4\x95\x1bFQg\xab\n.\xdf\x11\xd3\xc0\xc9\xb5D@\x92\x7f\x85:.{\x8e\xc0\x0e\xbf\x85uz\x13Alei\x03I<J\x04RI\x0f\x04\x922W\xf8s\x8f^\xd9\xef\x8a\xe5\xe6\x85\x9b\x8c\x1bw2\xc4G\x96-\'vv\xf0\xcd+\x05\x99\xd4m*\x17,r\x00\xf4\xc0\xe4\xfd\x075\xd4\x9f(+Gj\xe9\xb1\x902\xf9o\xb8\xc8W\xef\x0eyU\xeaFy\xc6>\xb5\xeca\xa9\xd9\xa9r\xe9\xb7\xcd\x1f?\x88s\xea,3M\x02=\xa4E^) ```

я не нашел метода удаления байтов из файла и хочу просто пересохранить его (это фото )

```
with open('abc.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(m)
```

но это вызывает ошибку: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

я понимаю, что m это строка, но мне надо байт объект, но с таким же содержанием (со слешами и т.д.)

проблема в том что если попробовать записать так: `f.write(bytes(m, encoding = 'cp1251'))` то туда приходит что-то такое:

`\\xe6@\\xd8\\n\\xac\\xa3\\xdc1-\\xe8{\\x01\\x9a\\xcdG\\xf2\\xc4\\x9b\\x0e\\xfc\\xb8U9\\xf9\\x90\\x0e\\xde\\x98\\xe7\\xeb\\xc0\\xe7\\xae|\\xea\\x92\\xbd\\xecvFWV\\xb9\\xa3m$e\\xc6\\x15eX\\x9c;\\x06\\xe3\\xe5\\xe9\\x9c\\xf5\\x00\\x9e3\\xef[v\\xd1\\xa4N$i\\xd1%B\\x0f\\x95 "GV\\xe8W\\xb6\\x07~y\\xdc1\\xde\\xb2\\x8f4Z}\\xc8\\x97/M\\xce\\x82\\r\\xd2K,\\xa02\\x16m\\xf2\\xbe\\xec\\x07c\\xd4(\\x1d8\\xc7\\x18\\xfeu\\xd6\\xdb34h\\xe6\\xd4\\xa32\\x852\\xcb\\xfe\\xb7\\x00u_\\xaf\\x03\\x07\\xa0\\xafN\\x84\\xb6\\xbfs\\x8a\\xaa]\\x11\\xab\\x12\\x9d\\xf1\\xed\\x99V5\\x93\\xf7\\xcaWqu\\xc7L\\xf5^q\\xcf=\\x0f\\x1d\\xebZ\\x0b\\xbb\\x8bh\\xee!V\\x02\\xdeVQ6\\xf5\\x1e\\\\\\xca\\x87#\\x9e\\xa0g\\xe8x\\xafF2\\xe6\\x9bJ\\xe9\\\'\\xf7\\x9c\\x93^E\\x9by\\xee\\xb0F\\xf7\\x8e\\xdd\\x9b\\xf8X\\xaf\\x99\\xd7\\x93\\x8e8\\xcb\\x009\\xe0\\xfe\\x15\\xa5g?\\x939(x\\\'\\xe6\\x0cs\\xe6v\\xe6\\xba\\x14\\x96\\xef~\\xe73Qm&\\x8b\\xd9\\x8d\\xa4hD\\x9b\\x1d\\xb9\\xce2[\\xbe?\\x1e\\x80\\xfd*\\xbe\\xe9#\\x98\\x88\\x972/\\xc8VhD\\x89\\x81\\xc1\\x18#\\xaf^OC\\x83\\\\5j\\xb9W\\x94i\\xc1\\xe9mo\\xa3\\xf2*\\x11\\x84z\\x1b\\xfaPV\\x0c\\xca\\x08Em\\xf1\\xa9a\\xc3\\x028=;g\\x9095\\xe9z~\\xd9\\xa3\\n\\x0b\\x81\\xb9[#\\xee\\x92:\\x0f\\xe7]q\\xc2)ET\\x93\\xb2\\xbd\\x8c\\xe7R1\\x93M\\x1b2%\\xad\\xad\\xcb6\\xe9KyK \\n\\xd9\\x01\\x88\\xc1\\xcf\\xb1\\xe4\\x8e\\xd5\\x89\\xa8_\\xb0,\\xf1\\x80Q0\\x87\\xb0\\x07\\x9f\\xd7\\xfc+\\xd2T\\xe1Rr\\xb2\\xba\\xe5\\xb2\\xd3\\xeff.\\xacU\\x8eJ\\xfaV\\xb8\\x929\\x89o\\x9c\\x9f7\\x8d\\x87\\x8fO\\xd3\\xb5q\\xd76\\xca\\xfb\\x98\\xb6&y\\xcc\\x8c\\xcc\\xdf\\x7f=\\x87a\\x80?Rk\\x8aT\\x94V\\x9d\\r!QJ\\xd79\\xddK\\x9b\\x82R0\\xb1>\\x11\\n\\x92\\xe4\\x1e\\x84\\xee\\xee\\x0f\\xe9YW0\\x0c$N\\xc1\\x19G/\\x92\\xdb\\xfb\\xe4\\xf6\\xf4\\x1cq\\xd2\\xbc\\x9cO4#x+\\x9e\\x85){\\xcfS\\x02x\\xe4\\x89\\xc9\\x8c\\xb2\\x82\\x0f\\xef@\\xf9\\x94\\x8eA\\x1c\\xd6\\x13\\x19Vei@uL\\xf6\\xces\\xc0\\xfck\\xcb\\xaa\\xde\\xfd\\xce\\xd85\\xd5\\x9b1mh\\x9c+1I0\\xdb@\\x03\\x04g\\xdc\\xf4$\\xe0\\xf1\\x9fNqW\\x0b\\xc0\\x91\\xb4\\xd72\\xc2\\x11PG\\x10\\xc1\\r\\x1bw;\\xba\\x1c\\xe3\\xf2\\xfc*\\xe9\\xc1\\xb9{\\xba\\x95\\xed\\x12"i&1<V\\xf3\\xcb\\x15\\xad\\xde\\x05\\xc4"L$\\xc4tb:\\xf1\\xdb\\xd2\\xa0K\\x99\\xe0\\x91\\xcc\\xb1K\\xe5\\xa6#\\xf3\\x14\\x0c\\xca\\x14|\\xa1\\x7f\\x96~\\xb4\\xaa\\xd3\\x96\\xb6wf\\xd1\\xaa\\x9aH\\xd5\\x86LF\\x97\\x98T,`

как мне получить верхнее значение без дублированных слешей, но чтоб тип был bytes?

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to open and present raw binary data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33145337/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто не делайте `str(data)`, оставьте байтами как есть. У байтов тоже есть метод `split`, так что можно сделать так:

```
m = data.split(b'\x2d\x2a\x2a\x2d')[0]
```

(предполагая, что под 2d и прочим подразумевались шестнадцатеричные значения байтов)

Если нужно редактировать байты, можно `bytes` привести к `bytearray`, тогда, например, можно будет редактировать отдельные байты по индексу. Или просто разбивать объект `bytes` на отдельные части, вклеивать нужный кусок, склеивать обратно.

## Ответ на комментарии

Создадим тестовый бинарный файл:

```
import random

with open('test.bin', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(bytes(random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(33)))
    file.write(b'-**-')
    file.write(b'Some text')
```

Откроем шестнадцатеричным редактором, убедимся, что там есть строка `-**-` (представленная в шестнадцатеричном виде байтами `2D 2A 2A 2D`):

[image: Скриншот]

Проверим наличие нужных символов разными способами:

```
from binascii import hexlify

with open('test.bin', 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)  # b':\xcb\x04\xd5n\xcd\xbe\xb1\x17\x86\r\xa4\xabM\n\xb2LUU\xa8\x0f\x98\xa9\x15\x0b\xeb\x14\x83\xd5\x04i\xc0l-**-Some text'
    print('2d2a2a2d' in str(data))  # False
    print('-**-' in str(data))  # True
    print(b'2d2a2a2d' in hexlify(data))  # True - но этот способ не надежный, т.к. сработает например и на байты a2 d2 a2 a2 d2
    print(b'\x2d\x2a\x2a\x2d' in data)  # True
    print(b'-**-' in data)  # True

    # Теперь проверяем способ из начала ответа:
    m, n = data.split(b'-**-')  # В m попадает начало файла до строки -**-, в n - все остальное
    print(n)  # b'Some text'
```

Скорее всего вы фактически дописывали в файл не текст `'-**-'`, а текст `'2d2a2a2d'` (не байты, представленные этими шестнадцатеричными кодами, а именно эти цифры и буквы).

Comment: увы, этот способ не подходит, для добавления текста в файл я использую hex code, и просто добавляю текст в конец, и в конце я получаю \xd92d2a2a2dc4f5a4  где xd9 идет из фото, 2d2a2a2d это цех код строки: `-**-`, а дальше текст, этот текст я получаю после split полученных  данных,  а потом из hex'a получаю текст, теперь мне надо надо удалить, я хотел все до текста просто записывать в файл, без самого текста и раскодирование как у вас у меня не работает

Comment: @NEStenerusnester вот как раз ваш способ не рабочий: если в файле есть строка `-**-`, то в `str(data)` вы не найдёте `2d2a2a2d` - вы там найдёте, внезапно, `-**-`. А вот если в байтах (сыром data) будете искать `b'\x2d\x2a\x2a\x2d'`, то вы его там найдёте.

Comment: однако, на практике мой код работает, я записываю hex код в файл, для перевода строки в hex я использую `binascii.hexlify()` и при чтении файла я получаю что-то такого вида: `\xb6Z\xfa\xcb\x18\xd92d2a2a2daba4a5c6f9d8` и прочитать `d2a2a2d2` я могу из файла спокойно

Comment: @NEStenerusnester, дополнил ответ.

Comment: использование термина "текстовый файл" для `'wb'` режима вводит в заблуждение. Не помогает, что байты со значениями, соответствующими ascii кодам для букв, представлены как сами эти буквы в исходном коде Питона (`b'a'`). Сами байты текстом не являются. Чтобы как текст интерпретировать байты, необходимо использовать конкретную кодировку: `unicode_text = data_bytes.decode(character_encoding)` Один и тот же текст можно представить, используя разные последовательности байт и наоборот одна и та же последовательность байт может соответствовать разному тексту, [примеры](https://goo.gl/NPq2ut)

Comment: @jfs, поменял "тестовый" на "тестовый бинарный", чтобы не было разночтений.

Comment: @insolor "тестовый" vs. "текстовый" — моя ошибка. Что характерно: несколько раз это место читал. Мозг картинку подменяет¶ Пункт про использование bytes literals с буквами остаётся в силе (тяжело убедить людей, что bytes сами по себе это не текст, когда они видят текст в исходном коде).